# Having trouble visualising how numbers lay in the complex plane and how that relates to the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

This is in the chapter on divisibility in number theory:

> Draw a figure that shows how the complex whole numbers lay in the complex plane.
>
> Use the figure to show that for every complex number $v$, there is a complex number $u$ such that 
>   $$
> |u-v| \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}} {2}.
> $$

I realise that $\frac{\sqrt{2}} {2}$ is equal to $\sin \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{4}$, but that's just confused me more than anything.  I can see that if I have two complex numbers a and b, and a divides b, there seems to be a difference of less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$ between them (this might be coincidence though).

I've also notices that the angle between a complex number and its conjugate is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  I used that in my fist attempt to answer the question, but I was wrong to the point I couldn't even get any hints on how to go forward.

It is important I really understand this, so I'm not looking for a solution to this problem, just to be pointed in the right direction.  I'd at least like to understand enough that I can email an intelligent question to my professor.

Comment: What an odd question. Shouldn't there be a complex whole number $v$ such that $|u - v| \le 1$? Just take $v = u + 1$.

Comment: Thanks for tidying up my question and tagging it correctly. I thought of setting v = $\frac{\sqrt{2}} {2}$, but then I don't know what the point of doing it visually is, or why we're not using 1 for example.  My profs problem sets usually build on one thing after another, but I don't see the connection to the previous questions in that exercise.  They have to do with looking at norms from a number theory perspective, then it's showing a specific complex number has only 4 specific roots.

Comment: I meant norms, not roots.